# ui-sref generates a wrong url with parameters

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ui-sref

I am using angular ui router.

But when I wrote a link to my current state, but with other parameters, the link is assembled wrong as you can see in the exapmle below. (The ID has changed in the options but not in the generated href attribute.

The id in the generated URL is the URL from the current.

```
<a ui-sref="root.app.list.detail" 
   ui-sref-opts="{'service':'ebBelegService','id':'463485'}" 
   class="ng-binding" 
   href="#/app/list/detail?service=ebBelegService&id=252237">

  ebBeleg 463485
</a>
```

Is there a better way to solve it than build the URL manualy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `ui-sref-opts` for this.  Instead pass the params as a second object to `ui-sref`.  Also, you shouldn't need the href object if you're using `ui-sref`.

```
<a ui-sref="root.app.list.detail, {'service':'ebBelegService','id':'252237'}" 
   class="ng-binding" >
</a>
```

**// Update**

As i the comments i changed a little thing.

```
<a ui-sref="root.app.list.detail('service':'ebBelegService','id':'252237'})" 
   class="ng-binding" >
</a>
```

Comment: <a ui-sref="root.app.list.detail({'service':'ebBelegService','id':'252237'})" 
   class="ng-binding" >
</a>

Comment: now it works. Thanks. You missed the () - but your approach works.

Comment: There are  also the `ui-state`, `ui-state-params` and `ui-state-options` directives  http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-state